# Comparing two different but related datasets

Tags: regression, sas

Background: I used a principal component analysis to re-define neighborhood boundaries. Each neighborhood is made up of at least 2 census tracts.  There were 40 neighborhoods in my old model. I have 45 neighborhoods in total under my new model; 13 were altered.

I would like to use disease rates by gender in each neighborhood to compare my old and new models.  I have disease rates by gender and year (2010-2012) for each neighborhood, for both old and new models in separate datasets.

I know qualitatively that my new model is a better fit to the data, but I want to find a way to statistically show that.  I know that a nested linear regression model isn't appropriate, for various reasons.  Can I preform a non-nested regression analysis, or is there a simpler way to compare the two models?